# Is it possible to go to another page with @ResponseEntity in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a page with many items on it. Each one has a button, that is supposed to take user to another jsp with another layout for detailed information about the current item. Can I even do this with ResponseEntity, as it doesn't redirect anywhere? Or may be there's some better way to do it and send my Object to the page? I tried "ResponseEntity.created(location).body(object)" but it doesn't do the job, I stay on the same page. May be I'm just using it wrong?

My method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/details+{id}"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Item> details(@PathVariable("id") int id) {        
        Item item = itemService.findById(id);

        if(item == null){
            return new ResponseEntity<Item>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<Item>(item, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [ModelAndView](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView.html). It's purpose is to return a view with attached model to it. So for each value of the id, you can decide a pair of view and model to return.

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/details+{id}"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView details(@PathVariable("id") int id) {

   String viewToUse;
   Map<String, Item> modelToUse;

   if(id == ...) {
      viewToUse = ...
      modelToUse = ...
   } else if (id == ...) {
      viewToUse = ...
      modelToUse = ...  
   } else if (id == ...) {
      viewToUse = ...
      modelToUse = ...  
   }

   return new ModelAndView(viewToUse, modelToUse);
}
```

Comment: That if/else chain is a bit ugly :)

Comment: Yep. I was actually thinking to suggest a better design pattern (i.e. state pattern) to elegantly handle the branches. But I found it a bit out of the question :)